# Cache a spatial lookup in Django

Tags: python, django, caching, distance, geodjango

I work with Python 2.7 & Django 1.9.

I managed to cache results of a spatial queryset when based on a polygon, but I can't manage to cache it when based on Distance from a location.

The error returned is: "TypeError: can't pickle Binary objects"

Any idea why ?

Here is a summary of the caching function:

```
qs = ThePlace.objects.annotate(distn=Distance('lnglat', populatedplacegeom)).filter(distn__lte=D(km=25).m)
cache.set(cacheid, qs, 10000)
```

For info: I also have several prefetch_related and select_related in the queryset.

Comment: Can you please attach the complete traceback?

Comment: Hi udi. I switched from caching the results to Memcached to caching the results to the database. I am not sure if it is related, but it is now working, so I am not able to reproduce the error anymore. Thank you anyway.